# Three.js objects masking video

Tags: three.js

We are creating an animated datavisualization.

We are trying to find out how to use objects to use as a clip mask a video below using three.js.  It could be a sprite sheet animation if thats easier.

Here is an example video of the end result:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjyjqnPzDHA&feature=youtu.be

It must work in IE10, which seems to be a problem finding a solution.
Can someone share an example?  Im kind of a newbie to three.js

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks in advanced!
David

Comment: seems you have to use WebGL to blend color but IE10 does not support it unfrotunatelly

Comment: No, I can't find any examples online

Comment: I just found out we only have to support IE11.  Dunno if that helps :)

Comment: Looking for something like this [example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_sprites). But the material should cover the entire group or object3d.  I tried today to add a material to a group or object3D (also its children) and it did not work